# Inspect specific WCF message

Tags: wcf, message, inspections

I want to inspect certain WCF messages not all.
We have some methods with a specific return type. e.g. :

`MyApplication.Entities.SpecificResponse`

I know I can clone the messasge, dig into the soap message, but it looks to be expensive to inspect for all messages.

Comment: Why don't you group all that messages into separate endpoint?

Comment: They are available in almost all endpoints. but not all methods return that type.